# Apache2 sever fail to start in the Debian 8

Tags: apache, server, debian

I start the `apache2` server in the `Debian 8` machine and have the output provided:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start
[ ok ] Starting apache2 (via systemctl): apache2.service.
```

Now, when checking the status, I find this output provided below,

```
$ sudo systemctl -l status apache2

● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─forking.conf
   Active: inactive (dead) since Fri 2018-01-05 18:53:18 BDT; 2min 56s ago
  Process: 9603 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 9585 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jan 05 18:53:18 debian8 apache2[9585]: Starting web server: apache2AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Jan 05 18:53:18 debian8 apache2[9585]: Action 'start' failed.
Jan 05 18:53:18 debian8 apache2[9585]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Jan 05 18:53:18 debian8 apache2[9585]: .
Jan 05 18:53:18 debian8 apache2[9603]: Stopping web server: apache2.
```

The line informs that, Jan 05 18:53:18 debian8 apache2[9585]: Action 'start' failed. I assume that means the apache server is not running.

I looked for the error log and find,

```
$ sudo cat /var/log/apache2/error.log

[Fri Jan 05 07:31:23.141452 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 1905] AH01916: Init: (local.test:443) You configured HTTP(80) on the standard HTTPS(443) port!
[Fri Jan 05 07:31:23.141542 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1905] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) OpenSSL/1.0.1t configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Jan 05 07:31:23.141550 2018] [core:notice] [pid 1905] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Jan 05 10:27:07.347727 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1905] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Jan 05 10:45:01.716439 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 1754] AH01916: Init: (local.test:443) You configured HTTP(80) on the standard HTTPS(443) port!
[Fri Jan 05 10:45:01.928468 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 1793] AH01916: Init: (local.test:443) You configured HTTP(80) on the standard HTTPS(443) port!
[Fri Jan 05 10:45:01.948283 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1793] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) OpenSSL/1.0.1t configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Jan 05 10:45:01.948331 2018] [core:notice] [pid 1793] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Jan 05 10:57:54.207319 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1793] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Jan 05 10:59:21.635105 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 1801] AH01916: Init: (local.test:443) You configured HTTP(80) on the standard HTTPS(443) port!
[Fri Jan 05 10:59:21.766752 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 1837] AH01916: Init: (local.test:443) You configured HTTP(80) on the standard HTTPS(443) port!
[Fri Jan 05 10:59:21.770769 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1837] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) OpenSSL/1.0.1t configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Jan 05 10:59:21.770827 2018] [core:notice] [pid 1837] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Jan 05 11:29:49.123102 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1837] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Jan 05 11:33:46.931328 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 1700] AH01916: Init: (local.test:443) You configured HTTP(80) on the standard HTTPS(443) port!
[Fri Jan 05 11:33:47.107058 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 1750] AH01916: Init: (local.test:443) You configured HTTP(80) on the standard HTTPS(443) port!
[Fri Jan 05 11:33:47.120610 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1750] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) OpenSSL/1.0.1t configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Jan 05 11:33:47.120650 2018] [core:notice] [pid 1750] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Jan 05 14:34:06.958963 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1750] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Jan 05 14:34:08.857489 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 31187] AH02311: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting. See /var/log/apache2/cxClient443.draglet.test-error.log for more information
AH00016: Configuration Failed
[Fri Jan 05 14:48:49.228927 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 2360] AH02311: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting. See /var/log/apache2/cxClient443.draglet.test-error.log for more information
AH00016: Configuration Failed
[Fri Jan 05 14:56:07.665868 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 4309] AH02311: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting. See /var/log/apache2/cxClient443.draglet.test-error.log for more information
AH00016: Configuration Failed
[Fri Jan 05 14:56:29.491940 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 4465] AH02311: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting. See /var/log/apache2/cxClient443.draglet.test-error.log for more information
AH00016: Configuration Failed
[Fri Jan 05 15:01:14.384576 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 5618] AH02311: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting. See /var/log/apache2/cxClient443.draglet.test-error.log for more information
AH00016: Configuration Failed
[Fri Jan 05 15:01:18.064625 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 5704] AH02311: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting. See /var/log/apache2/cxClient443.draglet.test-error.log for more information
AH00016: Configuration Failed
[Fri Jan 05 15:01:52.921632 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 5893] AH02311: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting. See /var/log/apache2/cxClient443.draglet.test-error.log for more information
AH00016: Configuration Failed
[Fri Jan 05 15:23:58.732664 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 11914] AH02311: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting. See /var/log/apache2/cxClient443.draglet.test-error.log for more information
AH00016: Configuration Failed
[Fri Jan 05 15:24:13.462265 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 14259] AH02311: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting. See /var/log/apache2/cxClient443.draglet.test-error.log for more information
AH00016: Configuration Failed
[Fri Jan 05 15:29:12.703894 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 15379] AH02311: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting. See /var/log/apache2/cxClient443.draglet.test-error.log for more information
AH00016: Configuration Failed
[Fri Jan 05 16:14:41.286196 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 26572] AH02311: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting. See /var/log/apache2/cxClient443.draglet.test-error.log for more information
AH00016: Configuration Failed
[Fri Jan 05 16:14:55.140590 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 26682] AH02311: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting. See /var/log/apache2/cxClient443.draglet.test-error.log for more information
AH00016: Configuration Failed
[Fri Jan 05 16:15:30.060982 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 26854] AH02311: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting. See /var/log/apache2/cxClient443.draglet.test-error.log for more information
AH00016: Configuration Failed
[Fri Jan 05 18:53:18.353757 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 9599] AH02311: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting. See /var/log/apache2/cxClient443.draglet.test-error.log for more information
AH00016: Configuration Failed
```

The error log for the `cxClient443.draglet.test-error.log` provided below,

```
$ sudo nano /var/log/apache2/cxClient443.draglet.test-error.log


[Fri Jan 05 07:31:23.141321 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 1905] AH01906: cxClient443.draglet.test:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Fri Jan 05 07:31:23.141365 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 1905] AH01909: cxClient443.draglet.test:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Jan 05 10:45:01.715668 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 1754] AH01906: cxClient443.draglet.test:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Fri Jan 05 10:45:01.716274 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 1754] AH01909: cxClient443.draglet.test:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Jan 05 10:45:01.928326 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 1793] AH01906: cxClient443.draglet.test:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Fri Jan 05 10:45:01.928366 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 1793] AH01909: cxClient443.draglet.test:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Jan 05 10:59:21.634605 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 1801] AH01906: cxClient443.draglet.test:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Fri Jan 05 10:59:21.634976 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 1801] AH01909: cxClient443.draglet.test:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Jan 05 10:59:21.766633 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 1837] AH01906: cxClient443.draglet.test:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Fri Jan 05 10:59:21.766671 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 1837] AH01909: cxClient443.draglet.test:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Jan 05 11:33:46.930717 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 1700] AH01906: cxClient443.draglet.test:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Fri Jan 05 11:33:46.931209 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 1700] AH01909: cxClient443.draglet.test:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Jan 05 11:33:47.106862 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 1750] AH01906: cxClient443.draglet.test:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Fri Jan 05 11:33:47.106917 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 1750] AH01909: cxClient443.draglet.test:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Jan 05 14:34:08.853654 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 31187] AH02572: Failed to configure at least one certificate and key for cxClient443.draglet.test:80
[Fri Jan 05 14:34:08.857467 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 31187] SSL Library Error: error:140A80B1:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_check_private_key:no certificate assigned
[Fri Jan 05 14:48:49.228822 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 2360] AH02572: Failed to configure at least one certificate and key for cxClient443.draglet.test:80
[Fri Jan 05 14:48:49.228920 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 2360] SSL Library Error: error:140A80B1:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_check_private_key:no certificate assigned
[Fri Jan 05 14:56:07.665783 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 4309] AH02572: Failed to configure at least one certificate and key for cxClient443.draglet.test:80
[Fri Jan 05 14:56:07.665861 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 4309] SSL Library Error: error:140A80B1:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_check_private_key:no certificate assigned
[Fri Jan 05 14:56:29.491840 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 4465] AH02572: Failed to configure at least one certificate and key for cxClient443.draglet.test:80
[Fri Jan 05 14:56:29.491931 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 4465] SSL Library Error: error:140A80B1:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_check_private_key:no certificate assigned
[Fri Jan 05 15:01:14.384494 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 5618] AH02572: Failed to configure at least one certificate and key for cxClient443.draglet.test:80
[Fri Jan 05 15:01:14.384569 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 5618] SSL Library Error: error:140A80B1:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_check_private_key:no certificate assigned
[Fri Jan 05 15:01:18.064529 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 5704] AH02572: Failed to configure at least one certificate and key for cxClient443.draglet.test:80
[Fri Jan 05 15:01:18.064611 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 5704] SSL Library Error: error:140A80B1:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_check_private_key:no certificate assigned
[Fri Jan 05 15:01:52.921550 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 5893] AH02572: Failed to configure at least one certificate and key for cxClient443.draglet.test:80
[Fri Jan 05 15:01:52.921625 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 5893] SSL Library Error: error:140A80B1:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_check_private_key:no certificate assigned
[Fri Jan 05 15:23:58.732592 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 11914] AH02572: Failed to configure at least one certificate and key for cxClient443.draglet.test:80
[Fri Jan 05 15:23:58.732657 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 11914] SSL Library Error: error:140A80B1:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_check_private_key:no certificate assigned
[Fri Jan 05 15:24:13.462196 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 14259] AH02572: Failed to configure at least one certificate and key for cxClient443.draglet.test:80
[Fri Jan 05 15:24:13.462259 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 14259] SSL Library Error: error:140A80B1:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_check_private_key:no certificate assigned
[Fri Jan 05 15:29:12.703818 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 15379] AH02572: Failed to configure at least one certificate and key for cxClient443.draglet.test:80
[Fri Jan 05 15:29:12.703887 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 15379] SSL Library Error: error:140A80B1:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_check_private_key:no certificate assigned
[Fri Jan 05 16:14:41.283388 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 26572] AH02572: Failed to configure at least one certificate and key for cxClient443.draglet.test:80
[Fri Jan 05 16:14:41.286169 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 26572] SSL Library Error: error:140A80B1:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_check_private_key:no certificate assigned
[Fri Jan 05 16:14:55.140487 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 26682] AH02572: Failed to configure at least one certificate and key for cxClient443.draglet.test:80
[Fri Jan 05 16:14:55.140582 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 26682] SSL Library Error: error:140A80B1:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_check_private_key:no certificate assigned
[Fri Jan 05 16:15:30.060854 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 26854] AH02572: Failed to configure at least one certificate and key for cxClient443.draglet.test:80
[Fri Jan 05 16:15:30.060974 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 26854] SSL Library Error: error:140A80B1:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_check_private_key:no certificate assigned
[Fri Jan 05 18:53:18.353682 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 9599] AH02572: Failed to configure at least one certificate and key for cxClient443.draglet.test:80
[Fri Jan 05 18:53:18.353750 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 9599] SSL Library Error: error:140A80B1:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_check_private_key:no certificate assigned
```

What is the issue here and how to make the Apache run? I'm using the Linux/ Debian for a month now and still not familiar with everything

Comment: What's in `/var/log/apache2/cxClient443.draglet.test-error.log` like the error log says?

Comment: hi @Joe I updated the question

Comment: Did you look at https://serverfault.com/questions/769356/apache2-ssl-is-not-working ? It seems the same problem.

Comment: @gile +1 for suggesting the forum, I was not aware of them.